# Scheduled task with at command (6AM)

Tags: command-line, schedule

im gonna reboot my server 6am every day, if my internet get disconnected and DDOSed.
Does anyone have an idea how to do the command "at" at a specific time, and "AM"? Thanks- My computer clock doesnt have AM/PM, but I suppose linux wont understand if I write 06:00, will it be on mornings or on evenings?........

(I tried this for a test: echo "reboot" | at 23:17pm today), but it says "Unknown pm". What should i do?

Thanks

Comment: Have you seen Ubuntu's Scheduled Tasks gui?

Answer (score 2):

**You don’t need the PM because there is no 23:17am**

Its a 24hr clock so just write it in 24hr format you cannot go wrong.

```
stephenm@mcr:~$ sudo at 6:00 tomorrow
[sudo] password for stephenm: 
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
at> reboot
at> <ctrl+d>
job 4 at Sun Sep 22 06:00:00 2013
```

Answer (score 1):

You most likely need crontab
Logon to the server and type `sudo crontab -e`. In this instance, the root user will run the command at 6AM enter your password
Select your preferred text editor - for example type 2 for nano.
Create a new line on the bottom of the file and type `* 6 * * * YOUR COMMAND HERE`

Obviously replace YOUR COMMAND HERE with your command, however in your case this will be `reboot`

Exit and save
The server will now reboot every 6AM